# 'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name when converting VARCHAR to DECIMAL

Tags: mysql

I am new to the community so please bear with me. I am working on a sum function that will take the values of 3 columns (Exchange, Commission, Otherfees) and give me that total based on row. The datatypes for these 3 fields are VARCHAR. I started by using a CONVERT function and then addressed any NULLs. Please see the query below:

```
SELECT SUM(
(SELECT(SELECT 
CONVERT(decimal(18,4), isnull(ExchangeFee,0)) AS decimal
FROM T_TABLE) as EXCHANGE_VALUE) +
(SELECT(
SELECT
CONVERT(decimal(18,4), isnull(Commission,0)) AS decimal
FROM T_TABLE) AS COMMISSION_VALUE) +
(SELECT(
SELECT
CONVERT(decimal(18,4), isnull(OtherFees,0)) AS decimal
FROM T_TABLE) AS OTHERFEES_VALUE) AS decimal) AS SUMMED_VALUE
```

When running this query, I get the message 
'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? Please only use the correct tag.

Comment: `SUM()` is for adding up results across multiple rows of a query. It doesn't make much sense to put `SELECT` queries inside it.

Comment: Really VARCHAR for Exchange, Commission, Otherfees????  Why are you making your life difficult?

Comment: I definitely agree that data typing would have made this much simpler but the tables that were built were already data typed as such. Something to take back though.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using the correct data types for your fields.

ExchangeFee, Commission and OtherFees are all numeric, so why store them in a varchar?

If the values should never be NULL, and here these look like they probably probably shouldn't, set them as NOT NULL and default them to 0.

That said, [mysql will convert strings to numbers in a numerical context](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) so you only need to worry about any NULL values which COALESCE or IFNULL will deal with.

As for the query which you want to sum the rows, all of the data is coming from T_TABLE so the general structure of the query should be:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ExchangeFee,0) + COALESCE(Commission,0) + COALESCE(OtherFees,0) AS SUMMED_VALUE
FROM T_TABLE;
```